# Why is JS variable undefined?

Tags: javascript

This is strange - I must be missing something! I have this simple js thing that goes like this;

```
<select onchange='my_function(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value),\"my_text\"'>
```

and the JS is simply;

```
function my_function(selected, text) {
    var link="file.php?var1="+selected+"&var2="+text;
    document.write(link);
}
```

But I keep getting link=file.php?var1=selected&var2=undefined

I have an almost identical function which works fine!

Comment: using document.write like that is not a good idea...

Comment: It would be helpful to repro this in a http://jsfiddle.net/ and link to that fiddle here

Comment: I am only doing that to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select html should be this instead:

```
<select onchange="my_function(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'my_text')">
```

You were closing your function call too early. Also, note that I've switched the outer quotes to be double and the inner quotes to be single. You don't need to escape the inside quotes, and it's more conventional for attributes to be double quoted instead of single quoted..

Comment: Actually, it was simply the misplaced bracket :( - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the second value to the function.  It's outside of the function call (and acting only as invalid markup).  Try:

```
<select onchange="my_function(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value, 'my_text')">
```

I changed two things here:

1. Moved the `my_text` value into the function call.
2. Changed the quotes.  HTML expects double-quotes, JavaScript can use either single-quotes or double-quotes.  So it's clearer to use double-quotes for the HTML markup and single-quotes in the inline JavaScript in this case.

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
<select onchange='my_function(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value),\"my_text\"'>
```

with this:

```
<select onchange='my_function(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value),"my_text"'>
```

because `\` is a escape character, and it causing to pass your text as `my_text` instead of `"my_text"` and in first one is not the correct string.

I think you try to add `"` quotation over the string, but query string is by default a string you no need to add quotation if still you needs then try:

```
<select onchange='my_function(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value),"\"my_text\""'>
```